# Is it possible to use vector arguments in Fortran IF statements rather than scalar arguments

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Rather than using three consecutive scalar IF statements I would like to use a single IF statement with a vector argument, if this is possible. I can't figure out how.

The reason for wanting this is to test it for speed. My code can run for days calling this section billions of times. Even a little speed up can make a large difference.

Here is the working code with three IF statements for a dummy scenario.

```
program main

!==============================================
!               Define variables
!==============================================

real, dimension(10,3)         :: r                              ! 10 atoms     each with x,y,z coordinates
real, dimension(3)            :: rij                            ! x,y,z vector of difference between two atoms
real                          :: Box_Length                     ! length of simulation box
real                          :: time, timer_start, timer_end   
integer                       :: timer

!=======================================================
!                   Begin Program body
!=======================================================
Box_Length = 1.0    ! based on a box of length = 1 since coords are randomly generated between 0 and 1

!=================================
! Generate random atom coordinates
!=================================

r = 0.0
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER (r) 

!=================================
!         Begin algorithm
!=================================

call cpu_time(timer_start)

do timer = 1,30000

do i = 1,size(r)

    do j = 1, size(r)

        if(i == j) cycle

        rij(:) = abs(r(i,:) - r(j,:))

        !==============================
        ! Apply mirror image convention
        !==============================
        if(rij(1) > Box_Length - rij(1) ) rij(1) = rij(1) - Box_Length 
        if(rij(2) > Box_Length - rij(2) ) rij(2) = rij(2) - Box_Length 
        if(rij(3) > Box_Length - rij(3) ) rij(3) = rij(3) - Box_Length

        !*******************************************************************************
        !   Question: Can I make it into a single if statement i.e.                    *
        !                                                                              *
        ! if(rij(:) > Box_Length(:) - rij(:) ) rij(:) = rij(:) - Box_Length(:)         *
        !                                                                              *
        ! Where Box_Length is now a vector and only the coordinate that triggers      *
        ! the if statement is modified. Meaning that if { rij(2) >  Box_Length - rij(2) } *
        ! only rij(2) is modified, not all three.                                      *
        ! I have tried making Box_Length a vector, but that failed.                    *
        !*******************************************************************************

        ! insert rest of algorithm

    enddo ! j-loop

enddo  ! i loop

enddo   ! timer loop

call cpu_time(timer_end)

time = timer_end - timer_start

print*, 'Time taken was: ', time

end program main
```

Thanks for any help on turning this into a vectorized IF statement. Also, I flip back and forth between column and row vectors. Currently column vectors are working faster for me. This IS NOT a question about column versus row vectors. I do my own timing and use the faster method. I simply can't get a working vector method to try timing against.

Comment: The if statements are equivalent to `rij=min(rij,Box_length-rij) `. I guess this is just a test case and the use of `size(r)` rather than `size(r,dim=1)` is correct in the real version of the code. As it is you have a bounds error and are doing an order of magnitude extra work.You might be able to exploit symmetry and avoid what looks like 50% redundant work for `j>i` but that is another question.

Comment: You are correct, in my real code things are much more streamlined. I like the idea of  `rij=min(rij,Box_length-rij)`. I tried it and it is slightly slower in this dummy example than the three IF's or the WHERE. But, in my main code, it seems slightly faster. A common method in molecular simulation is `rij = rij - Box_Length*ANINT(rij/BoxSize)` and this method is very very slow. it is half the speed of using three IF statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"if(rij(:) > Box_Length(:) - rij(:) ) rij(:) = rij(:) - Box_Length(:)"
```

can be

```
where (rij > Box_Length - rij) rij = rij - Box_Length
```

Not that it will not make it faster than an explicit DO loop, it is just a shorter way to write it. It can even make it slower, because temporary array may be used or the compiler may have hard time to vectorize it - in the SIMD vectorization sense.

I advise against using word "vectorization" to speak about the shorthand array notation in Fortran. In Fortran vectorization normally means using of the SIMD CPU instructions. The compiler call that vectorization. Your notion of vectorization comes from Python but is not used in Fortran an is misleading to other readers.

Also read https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/03/31/doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this to see why you should use just `rij` and not `rij(:)`.

---

TLDR: It is possible to write it on one line, but in Fortran array notation is NOT the way to make program faster. Often it has an opposite effect.

Comment: The (:) is good to know, although now I don't know if in the where statement Box_Length is a scalar or a vector. Upon running it, either seems to work. Pros and Cons I guess. In the dummy example using "where" without any "(:)" was the fastest. However in my actual code there is not a noticable difference. But, the "where" is nicer to look at, so there is that element. In lieu of speed, cosmetics win.

Comment: Either scalar or array for Box_Length works.  I don't remember offhand the rules if it's array---I'm sure you would need at least the same number of elements, I'd guess you need the same rank, don't recall if you need exactly the same shape, or only at least as many elements as rij---but it will end up working element-wise, so Box_Length(i) would be matched up with rij(i) for arbitrary i.